# How to be able to iterate through list in parent class to create new list in child class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python and coding anyway. I've tried few days searching about the use of parent and child classes and tried to create simple program using them.

I've 3 different classes where two are parent classes and one child that inherits from both of them. In my second class, I've function that returns list with depends of the arguments given to object.

My third class should generate another list by iterating through the list created in second class. I thought it would be simply task but just can't get my head around how to do it.

```
class FirstClass():

    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3
        self.a4 = a4
        self.a5 = a5


class SecondClass():

    def __init__(self, b1, b2, b3,):
        self.b1 = b1
        self.b2 = b2
        self.b3 = b3



    def function_b(self):
        list_b = [b1, b2]
        x = b1
        while x < b2-b3:
            x += b3
            list_b.append(x)
        list_b.sort()
        return list_b


class ThirdClass(FirstClass, SecondClass):

    def __init__(self):
        FirstClass.__init__(self, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
        SecondClass.__init__(self, b1, b2, b3)

    def function_c(self):
        list_c = []
        for i in self.function_b:
        list_c.append(i/(self.a1*self.a2))
        return list_c


a1 = int(input())      
a2 = int(input())
a3 = int(input())
a4 = int(input())
a5= int(input())


object_a = FirstClass(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)


b1 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())
b3 = int(input())

object_b = SecondClass(b1, b2, b3)

object_c = ThirdClass()

print(object_b.function_b())

print(object_c.function_c())
```